# Android 1.5 SDK + relative Layout + EditText stretches in landscape view

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext, landscape

I have been working on my first app in Android and have study
various beginners books on the subject. At the moment the first app is
purely for my use to make sure that I understand the language before I
step into the realms of uploading to the market. However it may get uploaded if I am to get it to work correctly :) .

My current issue that I have is that my landscape main.xml behaves
differently when run through the emulator to when I run it on my phone
(samsung Galaxy S2). Now I know that the screen on my phone is larger
that the emulator but I would have thought that the settings in my
main.xml would stop the edittext from stretching too much.

Here is my main.xml attempt 1 from my layout-land folder and it is my
Player2_name edit text object that stretches  :

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <RelativeLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/ android"   
 android:orientation="vertical" <----- tried this with
 android:orientation="horizontal"    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"    android:background="#006400"
    >

 <EditText    android:id="@+id/Player1_name"   
 android:layout_width="150dp"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"   
 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"    android:text="Player 1" />

 <EditText    android:id="@+id/Player2_name"

    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"   
 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
 android:layout_width="200dp"    android:text="Player 2"

 /> <RadioButton
     android:id="@+id/Players1_turn"
     android:layout_below="@+id/Player1_name"

     android:layout_width="150dp"
     android:layout_height="35dp"
     android:text="turn?"
     android:textSize="15px"

  /> <RadioButton
     android:id="@+id/Players2_turn"
     android:layout_below="@+id/Player2_name"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Players1_turn"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Player2_name"
     android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Players1_turn"
     android:layout_width="150dp"
     android:layout_height="35dp"
     android:text="turn?"
     android:textSize="15px"

     />
     <TextView
     android:id="@+id/Player1_score"
     android:layout_below="@+id/Players1_turn"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Player1_score"
     android:text="Score :"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> <TextView
     android:id="@+id/Player2_score"
     android:layout_below="@+id/Players2_turn"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Players2_turn"
     android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Player1_score"
     android:text="Score :"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> <ImageButton 
 android:background="@drawable/red_ball"  android:id="@+id/redball" 
 android:layout_width="65dp"  android:layout_height="65dp" 
 android:layout_below="@+id/Player1_score"

 />

 <ImageButton  android:background="@drawable/black_ball" 
 android:id="@+id/blackball"  android:layout_width="65dp" 
 android:layout_height="65dp"  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/redball" 
 android:layout_alignTop="@+id/redball"

 />

 <ImageButton  android:background="@drawable/green_ball" 
 android:id="@+id/greenball"  android:layout_width="65dp" 
 android:layout_height="65dp" 
 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/blackball" 
 android:layout_alignTop="@+id/blackball" />

 <ImageButton  android:background="@drawable/cue_ball" 
 android:id="@+id/cueball"  android:layout_width="65dp" 
 android:layout_height="65dp" 
 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/greenball" 
 android:layout_alignTop="@+id/greenball" /> <ImageButton 
 android:background="@drawable/blue_ball"  android:id="@+id/blueball" 
 android:layout_width="65dp"  android:layout_height="65dp" 
 android:layout_below="@+id/redball" 
 android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/redball" /> <ImageButton 
 android:background="@drawable/pink_ball"  android:id="@+id/pinkball" 
 android:layout_width="65dp"  android:layout_height="65dp" 
 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/blueball" 
 android:layout_alignTop="@+id/blueball" /> <ImageButton 
 android:background="@drawable/yellow_ball" 
 android:id="@+id/yellowball"  android:layout_width="65dp" 
 android:layout_height="65dp"  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pinkball"
 android:layout_alignTop="@+id/pinkball" /> <ImageButton 
 android:background="@drawable/brown_ball"  android:id="@+id/brownball"
 android:layout_width="65dp"  android:layout_height="65dp" 
 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/yellowball" 
 android:layout_alignTop="@+id/yellowball" /> <CheckBox
     android:id="@+id/Foul"
     android:layout_below="@+id/blueball"
     android:layout_width="100dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Foul" /> <CheckBox
     android:id="@+id/Sound_on_off"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Foul"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Foul"
     android:layout_height="50dp"
     android:text="Sound Effect" />


 </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my main.xml attempt 2 from my layout-land folder and it is my
Player2_name edit text object that stretches  :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <RelativeLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:background="#006400"
     >

       <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Player1_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

            android:text="Player 1"
       />



     <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/Player2_name"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"



        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Player 2"

      />
     <RadioButton
      android:id="@+id/Players1_turn"
      android:layout_below="@+id/Player1_name"

      android:layout_width="150dp"
      android:layout_height="35dp"
      android:text="turn?"
      android:textSize="15px"
        /> <RadioButton
      android:id="@+id/Players2_turn"
      android:layout_below="@+id/Player2_name"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Players1_turn"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Player2_name"
      android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Players1_turn"
      android:layout_width="150dp"
      android:layout_height="35dp"
      android:text="turn?"
      android:textSize="15px"

      />
      <TextView 
      android:id="@+id/Player1_score"
      android:layout_below="@+id/Players1_turn"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Player1_score"
      android:text="Score :"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> <TextView 
      android:id="@+id/Player2_score"
      android:layout_below="@+id/Players2_turn"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Players2_turn"
      android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Player1_score"
      android:text="Score :"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> <ImageButton   
 android:background="@drawable/red_ball"   android:id="@+id/redball"  
 android:layout_width="65dp"   android:layout_height="65dp"  
 android:layout_below="@+id/Player1_score"    />

 <ImageButton    android:background="@drawable/black_ball"  
 android:id="@+id/blackball"   android:layout_width="65dp"  
 android:layout_height="65dp"   android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/redball"
 android:layout_alignTop="@+id/redball"    />

 <ImageButton    android:background="@drawable/green_ball"  
 android:id="@+id/greenball"   android:layout_width="65dp"  
 android:layout_height="65dp"  
 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/blackball"  
 android:layout_alignTop="@+id/blackball" />

 <ImageButton    android:background="@drawable/cue_ball"  
 android:id="@+id/cueball"   android:layout_width="65dp"  
 android:layout_height="65dp"  
 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/greenball"  
 android:layout_alignTop="@+id/greenball" /> <ImageButton   
 android:background="@drawable/blue_ball"   android:id="@+id/blueball" 
 android:layout_width="65dp"   android:layout_height="65dp"  
 android:layout_below="@+id/redball"  
 android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/redball" /> <ImageButton   
 android:background="@drawable/pink_ball"   android:id="@+id/pinkball" 
 android:layout_width="65dp"   android:layout_height="65dp"  
 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/blueball"  
 android:layout_alignTop="@+id/blueball" /> <ImageButton   
 android:background="@drawable/yellow_ball"  
 android:id="@+id/yellowball"   android:layout_width="65dp"  
 android:layout_height="65dp"  
 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pinkball"  
 android:layout_alignTop="@+id/pinkball" /> <ImageButton   
 android:background="@drawable/brown_ball"  
 android:id="@+id/brownball"   android:layout_width="65dp"  
 android:layout_height="65dp"  
 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/yellowball"  
 android:layout_alignTop="@+id/yellowball" /> <CheckBox 
      android:id="@+id/Foul"
      android:layout_below="@+id/blueball"
      android:layout_width="100dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Foul" /> <CheckBox 
      android:id="@+id/Sound_on_off"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Foul"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Foul"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:text="Sound Effect" />


 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I think I know my own problem. I do not think the app is reading the layout in the layout-land / main.xml as I think I have misunderstood the orientation method I have used :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I thought in my previous comment - it is to do with my misunderstanding of how the orientation is handled . I have got this resolved now so I will mark this as solved